# APS.net core 2.2 - configuration to deploy to multiple iis with multiple sites

Tags: iis, configuration, asp.net-core-2.2

I have been really struggling with this.  There is a lot of info, but can't seem to figure out the basics to get started.

In ASP.Net, I would have done all this with different web.config files.

This is what the end result of what I want is.

I have a single server with IIS on it.  (say www.mysite.com)
I have 3 versions of the ASP.net core web site

- www.mysite.com/PROD
- www.mysite.com/DEMO
- www.mysite.com/TEST

I am using Web Deploy from VS to Publish these to the server.  I would like to have 3 different Publish profiles.  Each will use a different configuration and publish to the appropriate web site.

The end result should have these differences

PROD:

- ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT : Production
- Connection string : ... myDB_Prod
- SiteName : "The Real Site"

DEMO:

- ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT : Production
- Connection string : ... myDB_Demo
- SiteName : "The Demo Site"

TEST

- ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT : Development
- Connection string : ... myDB_Test
- SiteName : "The Test Site"

LOCAL DEV

- Use ISSExpress
- ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT : Development
- Connection string : ... myLocalDB
- SiteName : "Local Dev"

Note.  This is made up, but would answer my questions.  It is not what I am really doing, so please don't comment on that.   I would actually really like to be able to turn on Development by changing something in a config file on the server without deploying (say in the web.confg!)

In my research, I am getting really confused with all the various places to set config.  There also is changes in 2.2 and that is throwing me off.

I have been reading the MS Docs, but I must be missing something.  Not sure where to start.  appsettings.json, web.config, other config files, etc.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?   For starters, each of the above (expect for Local Dev) will need its own Publishing Profile.  To accommodate the differences in configuration (Connection String) you'll need different "Configurations" (currently you probably have Debug/Release only) for each one.   Last comment:  Your SIteName and URLs at the top aren't in line.  I believe you'll want to change either the URLs you have configured in IIS or you'll want to deploy to something like Default Web Site\PROD in each of your configs.

Comment: @Rich-Lang.  Thanks.  I will have a separate publishing profile for each.  In ASP.Net, I would have different configurations and matching web.config files.  This is where I am having issues.   As far as IIS, there is a domain mapped, so the publishing is fine.   I think there is something simple I am missing.  When I try to google this, there is too much info and much of it is not relevant.  This seems like a really common thing to do so I am not sure why I am having so much trouble figuring it out.

Comment: Please describe why cannot you follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: OK.  So sure enough, this was a simple thing.  My issue was that I did not know where the Publishing profiles were saved.  Once I found them I could add the EnvironmentName setting and all is well...    But... I would still like to be able to use app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); on the fly.  This should not change any of my appsettings.XXX.json.   Is that possible with an easy solution.